# optimization of some javascript code

Tags: javascript

the follwoing code

```
$.concat||$.extend({concat:function(b,c){var a=[];for(x in arguments)a=a.concat(arguments[x]);return a}}); 

$(document).ready(function(){

    //document ready

    var solobroadcast_template =$("#hidden_solobroadcast").html()
    var b = new Array();   
    b.push([{"indexname": "green", "url":"#Green"}])
    b.push([{"indexname": "red", "url":"#red"}])    
   //....... more elements come here 

   //how can we know b[] while the array b contain unknown keys
   var bindexes = $.concat(b[0],b[1]);   



    var convertedvars = {
        name: "sam",
        indexes: function (){return bindexes}

    }


    var output = Mustache.render(solobroadcast_template, convertedvars);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output;
});
```

as it runs on http://jsfiddle.net/mshannaq/ZqqMe/6/

as you can see the variable bindexes = $.concat(b[0],b[1]); and in this case its static for b[0] and b[1] but what shloud we do if we want to to cocat all the b array size . imagin that b array size may be 1000 element and its dynamic.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You could easily go through 1000 dynamic elements in nano seconds with a for loop. I don't think you need to optimize. The general rule is not to optimize until you have witnessed slowdowns.

Comment: if the b array have dynamic elements let says 1000 element how we will run the concat function

Comment: what if I don't know what is b size because it comes from ajax how I will do the concat function?

Comment: @DamienBlack "The general rule is not to optimize until you have witnessed slowdowns." Says who? How will you ever learn to optimize (or write secure code) unless you think about optimization (and security) with each and every line of code you write?

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating `b[]` as an array of arrays. As you have it, you're pushing an array of one object onto each element. Why not just push the object, then no concatenation will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add objects to the array instead adding the array:

```
b.push({"indexname": "green", "url":"#Green"})
b.push({"indexname": "red", "url":"#red"})

var convertedvars = {
    name: "sam",
    indexes: function (){return b;}
}
```

Then you already have an array of what you need, instead of concatenating all your smaller arrays.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqqMe/11/

Answer (score 0):

in this case to fix this we use

```
 var bindexes = [];
 bindexes = bindexes.concat.apply(bindexes, b);
```

insted of using

```
var bindexes = $.concat(b[0],b[1]);
```

and now what ever how much b array elements they will be mereged

http://jsfiddle.net/mshannaq/ZqqMe/8/

as says on  [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)